# PHP using $var = <<< EOM

Tags: php

Updating:

The php is considering the code beyond the EOM; closing tag.

Here is how my script is structured:

```
<?php
switch($x){

case "a":
$var = <<< EOM;
...the html...
EOM;
break;

case "b":
...some code...
break;

}
?>
```

And the script is giving erro just after the EOM;

Old:

I'm using the following code.

```
$var = <<< EOM

... some html ...

<?php 
if (date("j",strtotime($row["dinicio"]))==$i){echo "selected='selected'";}
?>

EOM;>
```

but it fails with the following error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING in C:\Apache\htdocs\ancp\adm\adm_functions.php on line 132

removing the $row['dinicio'] solves the problem. but i need this field

Any ideas?

Edit:

For more reference here a more 'complete' segment:

```
<select id="ddia" name="ddia" class="form-normal">
            <option value="-1">dia</option>
            <?php
                for ($i=1; $i<32; $i++){
                    echo "<option value='";
                    echo ($i<10)?"0":"";
                    echo "$i' ";
                    if (date("j",strtotime($row["dinicio"]))==$i){echo "selected='selected'";}
                    echo ">$i</option>\n";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
```

Comment: Uhm... are you sure that there's just "some html" between the `$EOM` and the `<?php`?

Comment: Yes. As you can see there are 131 lines before and nothing goes wrong. Futhermore as said removing the $row['dinicio'] makes the script works correctly.

Comment: What is the purprose of this? Is it supposed to put the PHP code into the variable, or is it supposed to include the result of that PHP code in the variable? Please fix the syntax errors as well...

Comment: This is an exceptionally poor construction. Try to refactor your code to eliminate the `heredoc` altogether. Consider using a template engine as this is apparently what you are going for anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't escape into PHP in the middle of a HEREDOC (the <<< EOM ... EOM; block) - it is supposed to be just a string.

if you are simply echoing this straight out to the screen, then do something like:

```
...
switch($x){

  case "a":
  ?>
  <select id="ddia" name="ddia" class="form-normal">
    <option value="-1">dia</option>
    <?php $j = date('j', strtotime($row["dinicio"])); ?>
    <?php for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++): ?>
      <option value="<?php echo str_pad($i, 0, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>"<?php if($j == $i) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>
        <?php echo $i; ?>
      </option>
    <?php endfor; ?>
  </select>
  <?php
  break;
...
```

Comment: Well, you evidently *can* parse PHP in a `heredoc`. But just because you can doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: fair enough - to be honest, i didn't actually try and run it - it just felt wrong.

Answer (score 1):

try

`if (date("j",strtotime({$row["dinicio"]}))==$i){echo "selected='selected'";}`

and using more spaces :D

Comment: Beware that `selected='selected'` is not valid (X)HTML. Escape the quotes using a backslash instead: `selected=\"selected\"`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a cleaned up version of your code:

```
<select id="ddia" name="ddia" class="form-normal">
        <option value="-1">dia</option>
        <?php $j = date('j', strtotime($row["dinicio"]));
        for($i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo str_pad($i, 0, 2, STR_PAD_LEFT); ?>"<?php if($j == $i) echo ' selected="selected"'; ?>>
            <?php echo $i; ?>
        </option>
        <?php endfor; ?>
</select>
```

Comment: thx Tatu,

But now i got anther problem. The php is going beyond the EOM; ending tag.